# Does understanding functional programming help in understanding popular javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am not experienced in javascript. I try to use some popular javascript libraries such as jQuery, Angular.js and Meteor.js.

I wonder if understanding the logic of functional programming (in javascript of course) will help in understanding and using these libraries better?

Comment: One shouldn't even think of using Libraries or Frameworks before having a solid understanding of the language itself. This for every possible programming languages.

Comment: Yes and absolutely. Lots of JavaScript code uses concepts from functional programming languages. Learning such a language - or even how to write in functional style - will surely broaden your understanding of JavaScript, as well as other programming languages. Paradigms are always good to learn. That said you'll be able to use jQuery just fine even if you don't know what an applicative is.

Answer (score 4):

Well JavaScript isn't truly a functional programming language. It borrows some functional idioms and the most important part is "Closures".

I would say study "Closures" carefully because it is such a powerful concept that it will help you to write clean and elegant code.

Also, I highly recommend that you read this chapter:  [Functional Programming](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html)

Comment: In fact, I wrote the question just while reading that chapter :)

Comment: "JavaScript isn't truly a functional programming language" - eh, sure it is? It's just not a _purely_ functional programming language. It's multi paradigm. JavaScript is as functional as C#, or Scala. It contains first class functions, closures and a lot of higher level code relies on map/reduce (flat)/filter to work. A language doesn't need algebraic types and static typing to be considered functional - I'm in love with languages like Haskell just as much as the next guy - but all those cool things aren't what make a language functional.

Comment: Well, Closures is coming to Java 8. So Java is going to be a functional programming language? Objective-C has blocks but still, Objective-C isn't a functional programming language. Functional programming isn't about Closures.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article in Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) specifically written for inexperienced Javascripters (sadly many of us think we are experienced, eventhough we aren't): [A re-introduction to Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)
It discusses, in simple terms, some of the most important characteristics and features of Javascript which are often unnoticed (sometimes confusing). (One among them is the concept of [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Closures))

Comment: Your answer leads up to addressing the OP's concerns but doesn't directly answer them. Please consider [edit]ing your answer and expanding on how the link you provided will assist in using the languages in a better way.